# Using vue mixin inside @Component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-mixin, vue-property-decorator

I'm using vue-property-decorator package and I want to use mixin method inside beforeRouteEnter hook.

What I did:

```
import { Component, Mixins } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { myMixin } from '../mixins';

@Component({})
export default class myClass extends Mixins(myMixin) {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.callMixinMethod();
    })
  }
}
```

This has a problem, as `to`, `from`, `next` and `vm` do not get assigned their respective types automatically.

So what I need to do is place beforeRouteEnter into @Component

```
@Component({
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.callMixinMethod();
    })
  }
})
```

This solves the problem of types, they are picked up automatically. But this poses another problem. Inside @Component mixin method is not defined. It says

```
Property 'callMixinMethod' does not exist on type 'Vue'
```

I tried to register mixins inside @Component like this:

```
@Component({
  mixins: [myMixin],
  beforeRouteEnter...
})
```

But that didn't help.

Is there some way to make beforeRouteEnter hook inside @Component see the methods of imported mixins somehow? Maybe extend `vm` with mixins somehow?

Comment: You could probably overload the call signature of `@Component` by augmenting it. The simpler solution is to call the decorator explicitly. `export default Component({})(class extends Mixins(myMixin) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out is that we can assign type to vm manually like so:

```
@Component({
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm: myClass & myMixin => {
      vm.callMixinMethod();
    })
  }
})
export default class myClass extends Mixins(myMixin) {
}
```

And myMixin looks like this:

```
@Component({})
export default class myMixin extends Vue {
  public callMixinMethod() {
    // do smth
  }
}
```